# Is it possible to connect from another domain to my App Engine with the Channel API

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, cross-domain, channel-api

I want a cross domain communication from my site to the backend at App Engine with the Channel . Is this possible and if so how? Because there is no domain parameter in the Javascript API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can...  I'm doing this myself.   you dont need to do anything fancy, just include the /_ah/channel/jsapi script from the domain of the app-engine app, and it should work

EXAMPLE:
from http://mysite.com/index.html

```
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>
</head>
```

then use the Channel API normally 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/javascript

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714958/how-do-i-turn-off-the-console-logging-in-app-engine-channel-api/

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me (GAE Python 1.7.0 development) -- didn't try live yet. I managed to get it working on by manually replacing the BASE_URL: `goog.appengine.Socket.BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/" + goog.appengine.Socket.BASE_URL;`

Comment: @mohabitar First thing after loading the /_ah/channel/jsapi script

Comment: Both solutions don't seems to work. :-(
Maybe something is changed in the framework? Or is this solution still valid?